# How I can integrate it?!

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, continuity, gamma-function

Consider some function $f(x)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. How can I integrate $\int_0^1 e^fdx$? Is there some theorem or maybe special cases?

Comment: Quadrature? Riemann sums? Series expansion for $\exp$?

Comment: There is a general method called the **saddle point method** using complex function theory (https://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node13.html)

Answer (score 3):

In case of integrating by antiderivatives, there is not always a solution. 
For example: $e^{x^2}$ has no antiderivative.
Numerical integration is a good option, because of continuity.